# Ansible group_vars environment variable subsitution

Tags: ansible

Put this in `group_vars/all`:

```
default_environment:
  HOME2: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}"
```

When using in a task to define environment:

```
environment:
  "{{ default_environment }}"
```

I get this:

```
The field 'environment' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: {u'HOME2': u'{{ ansible_env.HOME }}'}: 'ansible_env' is undefined
exception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>
```

Is there a way to define a group variable based on the current remote environment variables, `$HOME` in this case?

EDIT: Per request, reproducible case:

**test.yml**

```
- name: Test
  hosts: hosts1
  become: true
  become_user: user1

  environment:
    "{{ default_environment }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_env }}"
```

**group_vars/all**

```
default_environment:
  HOME2: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}"
```

**Output** when run with `ansible-plyabook test.yml`

```
PLAY [Test] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************


TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

fatal: [host1]: FAILED! => {}

MSG:

The field 'environment' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: {u'HOME2': u'{{ ansible_env.HOME }}'}: 'ansible_env' is undefined
exception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>
exception: {u'HOME2': u'{{ ansible_env.HOME }}'}: 'ansible_env' is undefined

        to retry, use: --limit @/work/ansible/test.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

host1                      : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is:

> 'ansible_env' is undefined

You did not gather the facts.

---

Run a play before the one you try to gather facts only, without declaring the `environment`:

```
- name: Test
  hosts: hosts1
  become: true
  become_user: user1

- name: Test
  hosts: hosts1
  become: true
  become_user: user1
  gather_facts: false

  environment:
    "{{ default_environment }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_env }}"
```

Comment: Actually this is printed during `TASK [Gathering Facts]` phase :)

Comment: Actually nothing in your question proves that.

Comment: In this case it tries to gather facts with environment set via `ansible_env` fact. A kind of chicken and egg situation. Use separate play to gather facts without this environment set. And try to add fully reproducible example to your original post so others can see full context.

Comment: @techraf And hence my comment providing additional information :) See the edit with more info in the question itself.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov OK makes sense, let me try that... Added more info, though it's not much more than what there was before.